# MODULE NOT FOUND ERROR: NO MODULE NAMED "speech recognition"(windows 10)

Tags: python-3.x

When I used " import speech_recognition as sr" ,python interpreter throw the error "Module Not Found Error: no module named 'speech_recognition".
I have upgrade the pip command also and I test the "s0eech_recognition" module using " pip show speech recognition". It shows it version as well. But when I used it in jupyter it throws the error. Can you please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: My python version is 3.9.2 and my pip version is 22.1

Comment: You don't say where you ran your pip command or what it was? There's [a lot of packages matching 'speech recognition'](https://pypi.org/search/?q=speech+recognition&o=). Is this the one you used [here](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/)? If so, **from a cell in your notebook**, run `%pip install SpeechRecognition`. Then restart your kernel and try `import speech_recognition as sr`. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more information about `%pip` magic command. (There's also `%conda`.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.